# Rss feed for a category in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed

I want to get the RSS Feed for only one specific category in wordpress. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 18):

specific category in wordpress :

```
http://example.com/category/categoryname/feed
```

Answer (score 4):

Typically, unless you've done some modifications to the core of Wordpress, you can add "/feed" at the end of a category URL and that will give you the RSS feed.

For instance, if you have a category "food" then your RSS feed would be example.com/food/feed

If you have a category base set under permalink settings /wp-admin/options-permalink.php  then it would be example.com/your-category-base/food/feed

Answer (score 2):

You can learn more about Feeds here:
https://wordpress.org/support/article/wordpress-feeds/

Adding `/feed` to the end of any URL makes you access the feed functionality provided by WordPress, including for categories.